# How to match specific word match when duplicate with prefix is present?

Tags: regex

I tried this but it matches all href.

regex:

```
(?!th:)href="(?!(http|https|\d))
```

String:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{css/fonts.css}" href="css/fonts.css" type="text/css" />
```

Playground: https://regexr.com/7rd0m

Expected Output:
It should match href="

```
href="
```

Comment: If you want to exclude it, it should be a negative lookbehind `(?<!th:)` or a whitespace boundary `(?<!\S)`

Comment: But I am getting this The "negative lookbehind" feature may not be supported in all browsers. Is there any alternate which can work in all browser

Comment: That is correct, else you can use a capture group if you want to match that specific part `(?:^|\s)(href="(?!http|https|\d))`

Comment: It matches spacehref="

Comment: Yes, but the capture group 1 value is without the space, see the part highlighted in green here https://regex101.com/r/CBq8CF/1

Comment: I tried with js example, There i am getting only one https://jsbin.com/vitanagefo/edit?js,console

Comment: And how many do you expect? Can you make your question more specific with the logic that you are trying to implement?

Comment: One which is without th:href I think I can go with negative lookbehind I see it is supported in all major browser.

Comment: Yes, so it could be either  either `(?:^|\s)(href=["'](?!https?\b|\d))` with a capture group or `(?<!\S)href=["'](?!https?\b|\d)` with a lookbehind.

Comment: I would try the [**pony**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) again at this point. Use a parser instead, that's what they were made for in the first place!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a regex, you can either use a capture group preceded by a match for a whitespace character or assert the start of the string:

```
(?:^|\s)(href=["'](?!https?\b|\d))
```

The pattern matches:

- `(?:^|\s)` Non capture group, either assert the start of the string or match a whitespace character
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `href=["']` match `href=` followed by either `"` or `'`
  - `(?!https?\b|\d)` Negative lookahead, assert that it is not directly followed by http, https or a digit
- `)` Close group 1

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/l3oUSK/1)

Or a lookbehind assertion [if supported](https://caniuse.com/js-regexp-lookbehind) with a match only, where `(?<!\S)` asserts  whitespace boundary to the left:

```
(?<!\S)href=["'](?!https?\b|\d)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kwaCKk/1)

```js
const s = `<link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{css/fonts.css}" href="css/fonts.css" type="text/css" />`;
const regex = /(?:^|\s)(href=["'](?!https?\b|\d))/;
const m = s.match(regex);
if (m) console.log(m[1]);
```

---

Another and perhaps better option using a DOMParser with a queryselector for `link[rel="stylesheet"]` finding the `href` attribute that does not start with a digit, http or https:

```js
const s = `<link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{css/fonts.css}" href="css/fonts.css" type="text/css" />`;
const domParser = new DOMParser();
const htmlDocument = domParser.parseFromString(s, 'text/html');
const styleSheetLinks = htmlDocument.querySelectorAll('link[rel="stylesheet"]');
styleSheetLinks.forEach(link => {

  const hrefAttr = Array.from(link.attributes).find(att =>
    att.name === "href" && /^(?!https?\b|\d)/.test(att.value)
  );
  if (hrefAttr) {
    console.log("Found the attribute name 'href' matching the criteria for the value.");
  }
});
```